# Blank Screen after launching/debugging ArrayList exercise in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, arraylist

I'm learning ArrayList in Java. I'm trying to add and print elements in an Array with various methods. Trying to run or compile the above code results in 2 "placeholder" print and the console hanging when trying to set String = Scanner value. What's wrong? Here's the code:

```
public class Arraylist {
    private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addIt(String str) {
        list.add(str);
    }

    public String toStrings() {
        int i = list.size();
        String prova = new String();
        while ((i < list.size()) && (i >= 0)) {
            prova = list.get(i);
            i--;
        }
        return prova;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Arraylist ciccio = new Arraylist();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Placeholder");
        String str;
        System.out.println("Placeholder");
        str = in.next();
        System.out.println("Placeholder");
        while (!str.equals("bye")) {
            System.out.println("Add new values");
            ciccio.addIt(in.next());
        }
        System.out.println("Printing");
        String str2;
        str2 = ciccio.toStrings();
        in.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: You never change the value held by str within the while loop -- it will never end. Ask yourself, if the variable used to test the while condition never changes, then how will the loop ever end?

Comment: Instead, have `str = in.next();` and then `ciccio.addIt(str);` within the loop

Comment: shouldn't ig get it from the `in.next()`? However, it never enters that while

Comment: `in.next()` will not *magically* change str, will it? You have to assign the String received from `in` into `str` to change it.

Comment: I feel a little silly asking this, but are you actually entering in a string at the command line?  The way I read your code, it should wait at str=in.next(); until you enter something on the command line. I assume you are, i just want to make sure.

Comment: Side recommendation: rename that class as it is too close to ArrayList for comfort.

Comment: ok, my bad, i understood it now. but my problem is BEFORE the addIt method. as I said, it blocks on  
`str = in.next();  System.out.println("Placeholder");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will never enter the while. i should start on `list.size() - 1` not `list.size()`. Also, you might want to append to that string, not replace it.

```
public String toStrings() {
    int i = list.size() - 1;
    String prova = new String();
    while ((i < list.size()) && (i >= 0)) {
        prova += list.get(i);
        i--;
    }
    return prova;
}
```

Also, it will never exit this loop since str is only assigned once.

```
while (!str.equals("bye")) {
    System.out.println("Add new values");
    ciccio.addIt(in.next());
}
```

Fix:

```
boolean control = true;
while (control) {
    System.out.println("Add new values");
    String temp = in.next();
    if (temp.equals("bye"))
        control = false;
    else
        ciccio.addIt(temp);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer(s). Now the while cicle starts but never ends (as you said) printig and infinite number of "Add new values". How may I actually block every iteration on waiting for the input and then resume it after a Enter Key Press?

Comment: Ok but based on your (helpful) answer, i might just use a `while (true)` and inside it declare and use a temp String. Am I wrong?

Comment: I changed the approach, this is a better solution.